# Android: How do you import portfolio from Google Finance / Yahoo account?

Tags: android, finance, stock

Does anyone know how to import stock portfolio from Google Finance account? I am trying to make a stock portfolio tracking app for Android, and would like to be able to sync with Google finance, or yahoo finance?

It's basically a list of stock symbols/ tickers, and maybe number of shares and purchase price.